# T-SQL IN Clause Combined With Case Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have query where i have a in clause combined with a case statement. 
the error i get is this:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

i receive in stored procedure a concatenate varchar value like this '2,3,4,5' and i want in my query to filter the ids using the in clause
but something i missing

someone can give me a hand with this pls?

```
@ids varchar(50) = '2,3,4'

DECLARE @mylist TABLE (Id int)
INSERT INTO @mylist
select CONVERT(INT,v) from [dbo].[SplitString](@cardtypes)

//result of @mylist
//-------------------
//2
//3
//4
```

and then in the query

```
select * from mytable
where
ctable.Id IN (CASE 
                WHEN ISNULL(@ids,'') <> '' THEN (select id from @mylist) 
                ELSE ctable.Id 
              END)
```

Note:
ctable.Id (INT)

If i have only passing one value it works but if there are more it breaks

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to mix scalar value `ctable.Id` and some resultset `select id from @mylist` here in one `case` statement.

This can't be done, but you can rewrite your query like this:

```
select * from mytable
where
    (isnull(@ids,'') <> '' and ctable.Id in (select id from @mylist))
    or isnull(@ids,'') = ''
```

Answer (score 3):

Out of curiosity, why are you using a temporary table?  You can express this as a CTE:

```
with values as (
      select CONVERT(INT, v)
      from [dbo].[SplitString](@cardtypes)
     )
select t.*
from <table> t
where t.id in (select v from values) or
      not exists (select 1 from values);
```